# Error when connecting to PPTP VPN

Tags: windows-10-mobile, vpn

I create a PPTP VPN in Windows 10 Mobile. When I want to connect, it shows this error:

> A connection to the remote computer could not be established, so the port used for this connection was closed.

What is this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: This sounds like it is failing to connect to the VPN. Is that VPN server available from your phone? Are you on the same network?

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that the phone is unable to connect to the VPN server. Possible causes include:

1. **Your server may be unavailable.** Try a connection using a PC.
2. **You're connected to a network which uses NAT**. If you're connected to a Wi-Fi network, the router needs to support "PPTP pass-through", since your phone's IP address is not a public IP address and that does not work well with PPTP. This solution also applies if (1) fails above.